# Error "could not find function nnet" in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the function nnet after installing neuralnet package and using the code:
    **library(neuralnet)**
and still get this error all the time.
Does anyone can help me to solve the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Function `nnet` is not part of the `neuralnet` package. The function `nnet` is part of the `nnet` package. You need to install the package `nnet` and load it with `library(nnet)`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is such a function in the package? 
It is not mentioned in the manual of CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf.